# Why Did Adding a New Column to MySQL Table Change FULLTEXT Search Results?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I recently encountered a curious issue with MySQL FULLTEXT search and I'm hoping to get some insights. After adding a new column to a table, I observed a change in the results of a MATCH() AGAINST() query, which was unexpected as the new column is not directly related to the FULLTEXT search.

**Context:**

I have a MySQL table with a FULLTEXT index on certain columns.
The MATCH() AGAINST() query was functioning as expected before the alteration.
I added a new column to the table (not part of the FULLTEXT index).
After this addition, the same MATCH() AGAINST() query on the existing columns started returning different results.
Details:

**MySQL Version:** mysql:8.0.21 (docker)
**Table Structure:**

**Before:**

```
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `reviews` (
  `Link` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Producer` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Year` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Reviewer` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ReviewerScore` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  FULLTEXT KEY `Producer` (`Producer`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `Name` (`Name`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `Year` (`Year`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

**After:**

```
CREATE TABLE `reviews` (
    `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Link` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Producer` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Year` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Reviewer` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ReviewerScore` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `Producer` (`Producer`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `Name` (`Name`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `Year` (`Year`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

**Result with Initial Table structure:**

[image]

**Result with After adding column to the Table structure:**

[image]

**here is my query:**

```
SELECT
*,
(MATCH(`name`) AGAINST("BRUT Substance Grand Cru Blanc de Blancs ( 05/20 )") + 
MATCH(`producer`) AGAINST("JACQUES SELOSSE")) AS relevance
FROM
  reviews
WHERE
MATCH(`name`) AGAINST("BRUT Substance Grand Cru Blanc de Blancs ( 05/20 )")
AND MATCH(`producer`) AGAINST("JACQUES SELOSSE")
AND (`year` IS NULL
    OR `year` = "NV")
ORDER BY
relevance DESC
```

**Questions:**

Why would adding an unrelated column to a table affect the results of a FULLTEXT search on existing columns?
Could the internal rebuilding of the table or FULLTEXT indexes due to the ALTER TABLE operation cause such a change?
Are there any specific aspects of MySQL's handling of FULLTEXT searches or table alterations that could explain this behavior?
Any insights or suggestions for further investigation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

I Was expecting the both tables to behave the same.

Comment: Run an explain on both queries and you will understand the reason... Mysql can use only one index at a time. It probably changed which fulltext index it used.

Comment: explain returns the same results for both
 
 
 
 "id","select_type","table","partitions","type","possible_keys","key","key_len","ref","rows","filtered","Extra"
1,SIMPLE,reviews,,fulltext,"Producer,Name,Year",Producer,"0",const,1,5.0,Using where; Using filesort

Comment: result for second table

"id","select_type","table","partitions","type","possible_keys","key","key_len","ref","rows","filtered","Extra"
1,SIMPLE,reviews,,fulltext,"Producer,Name,Year",Producer,"0",const,1,5.0,Using where; Using filesort